# Deleting <style> elements when adding new ones with JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a page that has 3 buttons that make the background change color. I know how to do this, theoretically. I've been trying to build the methods for changing the background color but whenever I change the color, it's because the new style element overlaps the old one(s), so I'm looking for a way to delete the previous one when the  new one is created but I've yet to find it.

```js
var backgroundColor = {
                
                red: function backgroundRed() {
                    var sheet = document.createElement('style');
                    sheet.setAttribute('id', 'redBG');
                    sheet.innerHTML = "body {background-color: red;}";
                    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
                },
                blue: function backgroundBlue() {
                    var sheet = document.createElement('style');
                    sheet.setAttribute('id', 'blueBG');
                    sheet.innerHTML = "body {background-color: blue;}";
                    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
                },
                green: function backgroundGreen() {
                    var sheet = document.createElement('style');
                    sheet.setAttribute('id', 'greenBG');
                    sheet.innerHTML = "body {background-color: limegreen;}";
                    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
                },
                deletePrevious: function() {
                   // ???
                   
                    
                },
            };
            
            var applyColor = {
                applyRed: function() {
                    //a method that when applying a new background color deletes the previous one
                    backgroundColor.red();
                },
                applyBlue: function() { 
                    backgroundColor.blue();
                },
                applyGreen: function() {
                    backgroundColor.green();
                }
            }
```

This is the code I've written so far. The thing is, when I run it, this is what happens: [Overlapping  elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vSkg.png)

How can I make a method that deletes the previous elements? Should I nest the  elements within a div?

Edit: Turns out I'm wildly overthinking this. I'm been learning JS for about 2 months now, still have a long way to go. Andrew Lohr's comment effectively replaces all the backgroundColor functions I created. I'm also new to StackOverflow so I haven't found a way to upvote his comment yet. I need to get more acquainted with the DOM and easier ways to modify it.

Thank you all for your responses and your help.

Comment: unless you have some requirements I think you might be over thinking this. Have you tried just changing the color of the body on each button press? For example `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"`

Comment: Have you considered just toggling classes to do this? Also using a lot of repetitive code

Answer (score 1):

You look like you're familiar with JS, so tell me if you need a example.

Make a style tag with the  'themeCSS'. Then, every time you want to add/replace the CSS, use:

```
  themeCSS.innerHTML = "so {   and: so;  }";
```

That way, it'll always replace the previous CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the entire CSS `<style>` tag just set a value in the class` attribute that sets the overall theme and all of your CSS is based on that theme.

```css
body.theme-red {
  background-color: red;
}

body.theme-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

body.theme-green {
  background-color: green;
}


.theme-red h1 {
  color: black
}

.theme-blue h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.theme-green h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Or, break your CSS into three files and only load the correct one based on the theme.

Or, break you CSS into three files and use [Alternate Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets).